# Is there a away of amount the on bits in of n binary length number in lognsteps?

Tags: binary

I'm trying to find out if there's away for evaluating the number of on bits in a binary number of length n using O(1)  space, in logn steps? 
If so- How?

Answer (score 0):

A lookup table will find this in constant time.

Comment: He also wanted `O(1)` *space* (he called it "place" instead of "space")

Comment: Oh in that case, this question is really a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question. I'm basically want to know what's the algoritham for doing it in logn steps.

Comment: strictly speaking, lookup table is constant space